# How to find inverse of $f(x)=(51x+51)^{51} \bmod 107$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse-function

Im looking for answer, how to find inverse function for this function:
$$f(x)=(51x+51)^{51} \bmod 107.$$

We can write it like this I suppose: $$ y=(51x+51)^{51} $$ $$y^{56}=51x+51 $$ $$y^{56}+56=51x $$ $$21*(y^{56}+56)=x$$ $$y=21*(x^{56}+56)$$, am I right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you find the inverse of $51x+51$? What about $x^{51}$?

Comment: See the linked dupe for how to take the $51$'th root, using $\,\frac{1}{51}\equiv 70\pmod{\!106}.\,$ The rest is easy.

Comment: We can write it like this I suppose: $$ y=(51x+51)^{51} $$ $$y^{56}=51x+51 $$ $$y^{56}+56=51x $$ $$21*(y^{56}+56)=x$$ $$y=21*(x^{56}+56)$$, am I right?